# Use Custom TableViewController or ViewController for this layout with Swift and XCode for iOS?

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, uikit, swift2

I'm new to software development and am working on a test project that allows me to add items to a list. I've found countless tutorials which showcase the basic structure for this, and have gotten up to this point:

I'm creating a UITableView that includes several items and their corresponding price in a list format. The tableview contains a list key and price key in the cell. If the Add button is clicked in the navigation menu, it leads to the attached screen where each item can be added to the tableView if both the namekey and pricekey are filled out before clicking save. I want the Viewcontroller for this to send each item back to the original listview, but i'm not sure if I should use a UITableViewController or UIViewController, or UICollectionViewController for the layout in Xcode, as well as how to implement this functionality.

Any tips or clarification would be greatly appreciated! :)

[List Controller](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HSnbu.png) and [Add Controller](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kUTrv.png)

Comment: I'm not sure if it makes a difference, but I am intending to implement this with a plist that stores the items in this array. So the items name and price key are accessed, stored, and added, from and to a plist file containing to arrays. 1) section 1 in the list, and 2) section 2 in the list. both sections have the same layout. name and price keys.

Answer (score 0):

Check out similar question that I answered a few days ago. That link contains the sample code of the user who had problems so you can download that as well so you can figure out how to do this: [NSUserDefaults not working with UITableView in Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34113130/nsuserdefaults-not-working-with-uitableview-in-swift/34120743#34120743).

In this other question the person was trying to solve an issue with saving the data which is something you may want to do as well.